# C++ Class Objects - traversing Objects based on Param

Tags: c++

I've looked a bit and cant seem to find a clear answer to this. I'm practicing some classes and Objects situations in C++ and ran into a situation I cant quite figure out.

Say I have a class that creates objects and assigns various values like below as a simple example.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class stackProfile{
  public:
    int id = 0;
    string name = "";

    stackProfile(int x){
      id = x;
    }

    stackProfile(string y){
      name = y;
    }
};

int main(){
  stackProfile Obj1(10);
  stackProfile Obj2("Jennifer");
  Obj1.name = "Alex";
  Obj2.id = 11;
}
```

Now say I prompt the user to provide me with either a name or an ID that they would like to search for. Say the user provides an input id of 10.

How can I take the ID the user has provided, match it to an object I've created and then return that objects name?

In this case for example, the user entered 10 as the ID to lookup, i would like to say "ID # 10 belongs to a user named Alex".

I'm wondering how I could achieve that, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Store your objects in a *container*. `std::vector<stackProfile>` will do.

Comment: This was what I needed and was looking for. Storing the objects in a container and then using the find_if algorithm to search them was what I needed. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

This is not just a C++ problem, but a data structure problem.

In C++, you want to use the `map` data structure. Java also has this data structure, but the fundamentals are the same.

You pass an ID in, and you get back the object in that index of the data structure.

This [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) talks more about maps as well.

You need to import the `<map>` class with

```
#include <map>
```

call.

Comment: [Alternative documentation link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). This one is harder reading, but it is likely to be more precise. If you run into problems with the documentation linked in the answer, see if this new link helps you out.